# How can I build a library as a .dll and not a .lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I got this c++ physics library [liquidfun](http://google.github.io/liquidfun/Building/html/md__building_windows.html)

Theyve included a visual studio solution for building the library for windows.
When I build it it gives me a .lib but I want a .dll so I can use it with Unity3d.
Is there a way of changing the build setting of a project in visual studio to get a .dll and not a .lib?

EDIT:
The very simple fix of just changing it in the project properties actually worked for me! This is probably due to the library itself being really well written.
It didnt work when I tried the same thing before I posted this question but that was caused by a problem with my c++ code

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity3d. Why does it need a dll instead of a lib? It's more complicated than hitting a switch if the library delevopers only inteded it to be compiled as static library.

Comment: This looks like a CMake question to me. On projects that build with CMake as the project generator you change this setting in CMake not Visual Studio.

Comment: try this: Project Properties > General > Configuration type > choose "Dynamic Library .DLL" however I guess it is more complicated than that...

Comment: It should be more complicated than that. If CMake regenerates this change will be removed. Also you probably also need a preprocesser definition

Comment: Does it give you **only** a lib? When building a DLL, MSVC++ usually produces a small lib on the side. This is called an import lib, and doesn't actually contain the code from the DLL - just the entry points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can generate a dll instead of a lib. To do this in VS right click on your project -> properties -> Configuration Properties -> General. In the "Project default" section go to "Configuration Type" and change it to "dynamic library .dll". Then do not forget to generate it ;)

PS : DLL, not >LIB of course ;)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to build your VS solution from cmake.
I don't have the parameter at hand right now but cmake can list the parameters for you.
I think it was `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS`