# .lib and .h to .dll (likely using a .def file)

Tags: c++, matlab, dll

So I am given a .lib and .h and need to make it callable from Matlab. I have been researching various ways to do this and it seems using Matlab's loadlibrary is the best way to go.

Therefore, I need to create a .dll from this .lib and its .h. I do not have access to the implementation of the .lib but do have access to the .h. According to this post: [Converting static link library to dynamic dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384932/converting-static-link-library-to-dynamic-dll) it says creating a .def is the best route. However, I have had issues finding resources on how to create a .def file and then use the .def file to create the .dll.

Can anyone offer any advice on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: The link you provided shows an example .def file and how to consume both the .def and .lib using `link.exe`. What else do you need to know?

Comment: It does not provide much input on the creation of the .def file, which is what I am asking in this post.

Comment: It's just a text file. The documentation for all of the capabilities is linked to from the link you provided. Please read it, and if you have any specific questions, you'll get a specific response.

Comment: So would my .def file look like this:

Comment: LIBRARY

EXPORTS
 add
 subtract
 multiply
 divide
 (names of rest of functions in .lib file)

Comment: ^the spacing did not go through but it is the same as shown in the other post that I have linked

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much it. The names of the exports are indented from the EXPORTS header. BUT... have you read the bit about calling conventions? Matlab almost certainly expects the exported functions to be stdcall in the C++ code (that is, decorated with the __stdcall keyword or a macro that uses it like WINAPI). This is NOT the default. The developer of the .lib must explicitly do this. If they did not you will have to write your own C++ to wrap each function in a function that is __stdcall. The link you provide has all that information.

Comment: So I can't figure out where to find this .def file. I can't open the .lib file (it cant be changed) and there is no way to navigate to the properties section from the .h. Side note: How would I execute that link command noted in the other post? Do I just navigate the library in my terminal and essentially copy and paste the command? Thanks again for your help, much appreciated.