# How create DLL from header and lib

Tags: c++, dll, lib

I have `Math.h` and `Math.lib`. How I create dynamic link library from this files?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384932/converting-static-link-library-to-dynamic-dll).

Answer (score 0):

You can create project for Dynamic Link Library (DLL) and add Math.lib as input library in project properties. Also you classes in Math.h should be exported (use __declspec(dllexport) and __declspec(dllimport) for that).

```
#pragma once
#ifdef MATH_DLL
#define EXPORT_CLASS __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT_CLASS __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class EXPORT_CLASS Math {
public:
    Math( double y );
    int DoSomething( int x );
};
```

Macro `MATH_DLL` should be defined in preprocessor definitions in project properties.