# C++ metaprogramming issue/challenge to generate a type based on it function calls

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I have a C++ problem. I want to generate a type based on the type arguments passed to a templated function of it.

Let me illustrate it.

```
class A  {

   template<class B> M() { }

   void Z() {

   // NOTE: Here I want to call to X on each type that was feed it to M.
   X<N1>();   
   X<N1>();
   ...
   X<NN>();

   }

   template<class B> X() { }
   };
```

For example

```
   A a;

   a.M<int>();
   a.M<double>();
```

then `a.Z()` executes ...

```
   X<int>();
   X<double>();
```

Another example to take into account unique types

```
   A a;

   a.M<int>();
   a.M<int>();
   a.M<double>();
   a.M<double>();
```

then `a.Z()` will still executes ...

```
   X<int>();
   X<double>();
```

Note that I am generating the type A based on the calls to M.
OK! I think that for that class A that's conceptually impossible because A is not templated type and then it can not vary in that way, In fact that's not possible for any type in C++ (I think). But I want you to get the idea.

I am looking forward for a way to confront this problem using meta-programming, but any advice or solution or reference is welcome.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @ecatmur we are using generic programming and some kind of optimization when creating some kinds of objects and we need to clean resources in a very clean way

Comment: If you want `a.Z()` to expand at compile-time, the trouble is that statements `a.M<int>();` and `a.M<double>();` are consecutive at run-time but entirely unrelated at compile-time.  How about `A<int, double> a; a.Z();` or `A a; a.M<int, double>().Z();`?

Comment: This cannot work at compile-time, as there can be different instantiations in different Translation Units. If you restrict this to a single TU, you could use [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790721/c-type-registration-at-compile-time-trick).

Comment: Why do you think the above is a good solution to your problem?  The clean way to clean resources in C++11 is to use RAII types that do the cleaning for you.  Which looks very little like the above.

Comment: @Yakk In fact, we are using RAII, but trust me I can't give you all the details. My answer above it is not self explaining ...

Comment: "My answer above it is not self explaining ..." -- that sentence makes no sense.  The above question looks like a classic X/Y problem, where you have thought "I have a problem Y, and if I can do X it will be solved, so I will ask about X".  But X as formulated cannot be done (at least not elegantly) -- maybe there are easy and useful solutions to Y, but because you aren't telling people what Y entails (at most vaguely mentioning it), nobody can help you with those neat solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No metaprogramming needed.

```
class A {
  using XPtr = void (A::*)();
  std::vector<XPtr> x_calls;
  std::set<std::type_index> x_types;

  template <typename B> void X() { ... }

public:
  template <typename B> void M() {
    bool is_new = x_types.insert(std::type_index(typeid(B))).second;
    if (is_new)
      x_calls.push_back(&A::X<B>);
    ...
  }

  void Z() {
    for (auto&& ptr : x_calls) {
      (this->*ptr)();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thats not work, you will generate for example if you call M<int> twice you will generate also 2 calls in Z. And that is not desired. I will update the question to clear that thing. But thanks anyway

Comment: OK that works now. Thanks. But to be honest I don't like the generated code. I will try to find another option before accept yours. But again, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I think you're interface isn't really MPL. To be MPL you'd call it more like `typedef MyType mpl::vector<int, double>` and then find a way to build a type that called `X<...>` for each type. However...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template< typename T>
void X() {
    cout<<typeid(T).name()<<endl;
}

struct A {
  vector< function<void(void)> > callbacks;
  void z() { 
    for( auto a : callbacks ) a();
  }

  template<typename T>
  void M() {
    callbacks.push_back( [](){ X<T>();} );
  }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.M<int>();
    a.M<double>();
    a.z();
    return 0;
}
```

does what you want.

> $ g++ --std=c++11 && ./a.out
>   i
>   d
>   Ss

[See it live](https://ideone.com/TWFfJC)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve similar functionality using `boost::fusion::set` and `boost::mpl`.

```
class A {
    struct functoid {
        template<typename T>
        void operator(T t)
        {
             /* do something */
        }
    }
    template<class B> M() {

        boost::mpl::for_each<B>(functoid());
    }
}

A a;
a.template M<boost::fusion::set<int, double, ...>>();
```

But, in this case, you need to know the actual types, or, register some callback in `operator()`.

Comment: Sebastian's answer is better.