# Boost.Test tests on a static library

Tags: c++, unit-testing, static-libraries, boost-test

I'm using Boost.Test for unit testing.

Because of several reasons, I would like to write the unit test cases on different static libraries.

The problem is that when I do this, the automatic registrar doesn't work.

For instance, if I have something like:

```
// foo_tests.cpp
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE "Foo"
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( Bar )
{
    BOOST_CHECK( false );
}
// used to generate libFooTests.a

// main.cpp
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
// used to generate main.o
```

Then, if I link main.o with libFooTests.a and execute the final binary, it says:

`Test setup error: test tree is empty`

Everything works just fine if I create the binary from the source codes directly, but I wan't to be able to write unit tests inside static libraries using automatic registration.

Can I achieve this?

Is there some macro I need to define? Some symbol that I need to export from libFooTests.a?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to force inclusion of "unused" object definitions in a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383602/how-to-force-inclusion-of-unused-object-definitions-in-a-library)

That's your same problem and you'll have to derive a solution similar to what I did in my answer.